# How do I remove a migrated question?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, migration

I have a question I created on stackoverflow.com which was migrated to superuser.com, the question was answered on superuser.com but still remains in my questions tab in SO, how do I remove/hide these?

I've now created this as a [Feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31552/could-we-have-questions-grouped-into-status-unanswered-closed-migrated).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't.

Migrated questions remain yours on the original site until they are deleted. The question becomes a place-holder for Google Searches and for duplicate question closures. It is still a question asked by you and therefore it is not disassociated from your account.

These migrations stubs will be automatically removed after 30 days, but as mentioned by [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31538/how-do-i-remove-a-migrated-question/31545#31545) you can also flag it for moderator attention and it will be deleted.

Comment: Thankyou for this diago, I don't mind it still hanging around though I would like a way to move it off my `Questions` section and placed in a `Migrated` section, would this sound like a viable feature request do you think?

Comment: Due to the small amount of questions that get migrated I really don't believe personally that it is viable. However it will never hurt to create a feature request for it and get the opinion of other users.

Comment: Thankyou Diago, new feature request created.

Answer (score 4):

You can flag the question for moderator attention if you really want it deleted, and a moderator can do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for this Jeff, there's not need to require attention for closing, though I would like it shifted to another section if it were possible instead of being in my `Questions` section.