# Could we have questions grouped into status (unanswered, closed, migrated)

Tags: feature-request, questions

As I ask more questions I find myself looking through to find my current open questions. Usually these are always at the top when sorted by "newest" however "votes" is the default sort oder.

If we had additional tabls for "closed" and "migrated" this would help release a bit of the clutter as those questions I rarely wish to look at.

Comment: I support this idea.  It's something that I have felt has been missing since day one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I took was to do a search for questions I've asked that are still open/need to be answered.  I did that by using the advanced search criteria of my userID, `hasaccepted:0`, `closed:0`, and `wiki:0`.  I wind up with a URL that looks like this (linking to mine specifically):

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A[STACKOVERFLOW_ID]+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3A0+wiki%3A0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6504+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3A0+wiki%3A0).

Doesn't deal with `migrated` questions as those are treated as `closed` (I think), but it quickly gives you all your open questions.

Comment: Thanks Agent, this works a treat.

Comment: btw, sorry for the delay, was away on break.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have more luck asking for a greasemonkey script to do that, I doubt it'll be implemented in the engine

Comment: That's a shame, and I really would love to see this added as it would release me from the burden of searching through my questions and mentally filtering. I'm also a safari user so greasemonkey isn't really a solution for me.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a good idea, just telling you how reality is :) (feature-requests are not easily implemented around here...)

Comment: I bet that if you asked Jeff, he'd say adding barriers to having people ask lots of questions at the same time and not helping them when some of them are closed is a feature. And if he said that I'd have to agree with him. If you're asking a lot of questions simultaneously and a bunch of them are getting closed and migrated, then you, as a user, are a net drain on the community's generosity.

Comment: I'll get them all if it's the last thing I ever do!

Comment: @Gargamel, I wouldn't say I'm creating a lot of questions, though I find that when I do ask a question it goes to the bottom of the list as the default sort order is by "votes". I do have a couple that are unanswered and old, and those that are migrated I don't care for seeing any more. I was trying to think of a way to represent this in a way that's more fluid.