# Inconsistency between points

Tags: support, migrated-questions

One of my questions has been migrated and it's still here as an orphan.
[image]

When I click on it I'm redirected to migrated page.
[image]

The number of points don't match. Should they match? If not, should the orphans be deleted? How is this done? In time or should I ask for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove a migrated question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31538/how-do-i-remove-a-migrated-question), [Do closed questions ever get deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1867)

Answer (score 3):

Votes on negatively scored questions/answers are not migrated, so there can be a score discrepancy.

As for the original question, we have a weekly task that deletes any over 30 days old, so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: May I ask what is the period? Is this process performed by machine or by some workers?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more accurate information.

Answer (score 2):

They are actually two separate questions. There is one question on the new site and one question still on SO. The question on SO has been closed as off topic and set to "migrated to some site" so it redirects there. Eventually, the question on SO will get deleted.

It's just like on any forum system when you move a question to some other board. Usually you leave a "this has been moved to..." topic in the original board, where some users may expect to still see it, so people can follow to the new board.

Comment: Can I achieve for such orphans to be deleted? Here I don't have so many questions but on stackoverflow I often go back (and look for some unanswered questions and decide if I can proceed with them with my new knowledge or start a bounty) and the migrated orphans are making this process more difficult and confusing. At the first sight the question is opened but when I click on it I'll found out it's closed.

Comment: @xralf The stub is there so that links don't get broken.  Look for `[migrated]` on the end and your confusion should disappear.

Comment: @MatthewRead If the [migrated] keyword would be at the beginning or even instead of the (votes, answer, views) triple it could be seen at the first sight. Actually the (votes, answer, vies) triple is useless for the migrated question because on migrated sites these information is different.

Comment: Man, you don't know how tempted I am to click that down arrow for you comparing Stack Overflow to "any forum system".

Comment: @Cody: I'm not comparing the whole of Stack Overflow to a forum system, I'm only comparing the migration of questions between sites to the moving of topics between boards.