# Notifications for new comments to my questions

Tags: support, notifications

When I open some SE site I usually see in my inbox notifications about new posts.

I noticed it already several times that not all new comments are notified. I clicked on my question and found out there is a new comment which I wasn't notified about, I looked to the inbox and it wasn't in history.

Is this a bug or is it normal that not all comments are notified? Due to this feature the communication can get stuck.

The question (the only one I can now refer to) may be deleted soon (I flagged it as duplicate). [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124924/inconsistency-between-points) one. I wasn't notified about the comment under it and two last comments under the only answer.

Comment: If this is bug it is hard to reproduce/ find out details. IMO, would be better if you will point to specific posts.

Comment: @om-nom-nom See question edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it wasn't your post. When it's comments on someone else's question or answer (even if it's an answer to your question), you only get notified if the comment is directed at you, specifically. Those conditions are met if you and the post's owner were the only two commenters on the post (so far), *or* your username is specifically [@mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/167443) in the comment itself.

Comment: OK. This would explain two comments from three. The comment directly below the question by Cody Gray wasn't notified too.

Comment: @xralf: That comment was automatically generated by the system (on behalf of Cody) when he voted to close your question as a duplicate. I'm not sure if those comments are supposed to be notified or not.

Comment: And comment under the answer doesn't contain your nickname `@animuson`, but maybe AI recognized that it's for you.

Comment: OK, this would explain this case, but I have a feeling there was sometimes information for me (but maybe it was similar case to this one).

Comment: @xralf: When it doesn't meet those two conditions I mentioned in the answer, it assumes that the comment is for the post owner (but the post's owner is *always* notified of new comments on their post anyways).

Comment: OK, I understand now.