# Possible Error On Link Migration

Tags: support, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a migrated question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31538/how-do-i-remove-a-migrated-question)

I'm new. I recently posted this question on Stack Overflow:

> How can I install GCC on Mac OS X Lion without Xcode [migrated]

It redirects properly after it was migrated, but it's been several days, and it still shows up in my stack overflow account.  Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's normal.

The migration stub will be automatically deleted after a month, we keep them around for a while just in case the migration is rejected.